# C# Docker container System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (<URL>:4003)

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dns

I have build a docker containerized .NET 8 application (base image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine) that needs to make a call to a URL pointing to specific port, https://URL.com:4003.

I created the HttpClient like so

```
 using (var newClient = new HttpClient())
 {
     newClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://URL:4003/");
     newClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
     newClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


     HttpResponseMessage newResponse = await newClient.PostAsJsonAsync("route/path", requestMessage);

     stringRES = newResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

     Console.WriteLine(stringRES );
 }
```

When send the request, I get the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (URL:4003)
2024-02-21 16:31:37  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean useAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at CM..Utils.HttpClientHelper.SendRequestAsync(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption completionOption) in /src/CM./Utils/HttpClientHelper.cs:line 15
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at CM..Utils.HttpClientHelper.SendRequestAndGetResponseAsync(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions) in /src/CM./Utils/HttpClientHelper.cs:line 42
2024-02-21 16:31:37    at CM..Services.MessageProcessorService.SendEmail(ConnectorNotificationRequestDTO request) in /src/CM./Services/MessageProcessorService.cs:line 136
2024-02-21 16:31:37 
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
2024-02-21 16:31:31    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/CM./Program.cs:line 33
```

What I have tried and that works:

- Switch the URL to the IP with the PORT, so https://IP:4003 .
- Use URL and specify google DNS in the docker run command.
- Executed curl inside the container's terminal using the URL with no DNS specified in the docker run command.
- Created a console application and containerized. FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0

What am I doing wrong? Is this an issue related to the System.Net.Sockets library ?

I need to use the URL and not the IP.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue and work around.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/98794#issuecomment-1961361998

[Terminal showing problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2eCQ.png)

I performed nslookup with Docker's DNS server, 127.0.0.11 and I got a SERVFAIL.
This DNS server is set in /etc/resolv.conf in the ALPINE image. When I switched to googles DNS, it worked.

Also when I performed ping, I would get bad address.

I switched to image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 and it worked fine.